# Is it possible to tell apart real and testnet Integrated Address

Tags: testnet, integrated-address

Real address has network byte `0x12`, testnet address has `0x35` and integrated addresses all have `0x13`. At least this is what I learned from different resources online.

Is it possible to tell whether the address behind IA is a real or testnet one? Or the IAs for addresses with the same pubkeys are indistinguishable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testnet integrated addresses have 0x36 as prefix.

See src/cryptonote_config.h